# UDP livestream (GoPro Hero4) opens using OpenCV in python but not in C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, udp, gopro

i want to do image processing on a GoPro Hero4 Black livestream using OpenCV in C++. The firmware version is 5.0.

With python it successfully works. When i implement it the same (!) way in C++ status 31 and 32 switch to 1 when opening the VideoCapture, so the livestream is started and the client is connected. However, a following cap.isOpen() returns false. I need to add that the cap.open(...) command lets the program stop for some seconds which is unplausible.

The code in python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import time
import socket
from goprocam import GoProCamera
from goprocam import constants
import requests

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
t=time()

url     = "http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&a1=proto_v2&c1=restart"
payload = {  }
headers = {}
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("udp://10.5.5.9:8554")

while (cap.isOpened()):
    nmat, frame = cap.read()
    if nmat == True:
        cv2.imshow("GoPro OpenCV", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    if time() - t >= 2.5:
        sock.sendto("_GPHD_:0:0:2:0.000000\n".encode(), ("10.5.5.9", 8554))

        t=time()
# When everything is done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code in C++

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl\curl.h>
#include <boost/exception/exception.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    CURL* curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=start");
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/execute?p1=gpStream&c1=restart");
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }

    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver(ioService);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint dest(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.5.5.9"), 8554);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket sock(ioService, boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    sock.send_to(boost::asio::buffer("_GPHD_:0:0:2:0.000000\n", 22), dest);
    
    VideoCapture cap;

    cap.open("udp://10.5.5.9:8554");

    while (cap.isOpened() )
    {
        std::cout << "is open" << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the issue?

I also tried different API references for VideoCapture

```
cap.open("udp://10.5.5.9:8554", CAP_ANY);
```

```
cap.open("udp://10.5.5.9:8554", CAP_FFMPEG);
```

I also tried using the @ prefix

```
cap.open("udp://@10.5.5.9:8554", CAP_ANY);
```

UPDATE:
I can't test the correct execution of the VideoCapture backend since it seems like the laptop webcam cant be opened with CAP_FFMPEG in python.
However, when i let the laptop webcam run by declaring index 0 and using the CAP_FFMPEG backend i get the same behaviour as when i declare the gopro udp livestream.

```
cap.open(0, CAP_FFMPEG);
```

Comment: In your example `cv::VideoCapture cap` declaration is missing.

Comment: thats right.. i unintentionally deleted it when i paste in stackoverflow. It is now there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to deactivate the windows firewall for private networks. Cant be more trivial but in case someone struggles at that point...here is the hint :)